# Компилятор для С поддерживающий стандарт С11 для Windows 7

Tags: c, windows-7, компилятор, c11

Какой компилятор языка С поддерживает стандарт С11 и может быть установлен в операционной системе Microsoft Windows Домашняя расширенная SP1 ?

Comment: Например, [gcc](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор `gcc`, который портирован под Windows в проекте [MinGW-w64.](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)

При компиляции нужно указывать флаг, какой конкретно использовать стандарт:

```
gcc -std=c11
```

Подробнее, про поддерживаемые стандарты `gcc`  можно посмотреть тут: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html